# Can't parse date with golang, unexpected "e" string

Tags: date, go

I'm trying to parse a date string `June, 24 2022`,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Parse("Jan, 02 2006", "June, 24 2022"))
}
```

And it fails:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC parsing time "June, 24 2022" as "Jan, 02 2006": cannot parse "e, 24 2022" as ", "
```

Looks like golang mistakenly took "June" as "Jun", how can I fix it?

Comment: use `January` instead of `Jan`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using full month names, then your format string needs "January", not "Jan".